# Определение ширины блока

Tags: javascript

Как определить в javascript ширину блока? у меня offsetWidth и clientWidth почему то  не работают(

Comment: на чистом js, или допустимо jQuery?

Comment: через консоль получается, а через файл нет( в чем может быть проблема?

     (Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetWidth' of null)

 ошибка которая выводится

Comment: эта ошибка означает что вы пытаетесь прочитать проперть объекта, которого нет. проверьте ваш код. или выложите на jsfiddle.

Comment: но почему тогда с консоли работает?

Comment: вы предлагаете по одной строчке ошибки определить, что у вас происходит? мб у вас на момент запроса проперти еще не создан объект...

Comment: @Dikaz, кидайте код на http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/M3fNe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

скорее всего ваша проблема в том, что на момент выполнения этого скрипта объекты еще не укспели создаться. объявите вашу функцию, работающую с объектами, в $(document).ready(...)

UPD:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    //код
});
```

Comment: но я пишу не на jquery, как на чистом javascript это сделать?

Comment: а)все)просто скрипт в конец написал)